# Django + Ajax w/jQuery : Serialize & Decode

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I am attempting to write my first Ajax call to POST data into a Django view. I cannot, for the life of me, determine where I have an error. I believe the problem is that I cannot determine where I should process the json data dump in my Django view. Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

the Django view:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():

        u = mod.Applicant.objects.get(id = pulled_Applicant_ID)
        new_joint_owner = forms_a.AssetJointOwnerForm(request.POST.get('asset_owner'))

        if new_joint_owner.is_valid():
            new_joint_owner.save(commit=False)
            new_joint_owner.applicant= u
            new_joint_owner.save()

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': True}), mimetype='application/json')

        else:
            errors = new_joint_owner.errors
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(errors))
```

my jQuery/Ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.joint_owner_submit_btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var current_div = $(this).parents('.joint_owner_workspace');
    var form_to_hide = $(this).parents('div#content').children('form#form_entry_input');
    //var details = $('form#joint_owner_add_form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: '/input/assets/joint_owner/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'asset_owner' : $('form#joint_owner_add_form').serializeArray() },

        success: function(){
            form_to_hide.slideUp();
            current_div.slideDown();
            },

        fail: function (forms) {
            $('form#joint_owner_add_form').html(forms);
            console.log(forms);
            },
        });
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: try JSON.stringify($('form#joint_owner_add_form').serializeArray())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, it looks like you are sending a json string as the payload for the whole form. This is certainly going to make things confusing to your form handler. You have two choices: either make the browser side send normal form data, or convert it to json and deserialize it into a Python object before sending to your django form class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't pass the [CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/). You'll find a script snippet in the django documentation.
You might also want to look into django-restframework.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include the code with the CSRF token header. I will add that now.  I get a 500 response, which I should also include.

Comment: @SpencerBates btw: since django 1.7 there is a `JSONResponse`

Comment: oh, thanks. I should probably use that since i'm using 1.7. lol. obviously quite new to this whole json/ajax thing

Comment: Don't worry, but you should really look into django-restframework especially if you want to build a front end based on angular & co.

Answer (score 1):

I am reading your django view and I see a bunch syntax errors:

```
        new_joint_owner.applicant= u
        new_joint_owner.save()here
```

First try fixing those if they are in your code. See if the 500 persists.

Comment: not quite sure how that "here" got into the code (its not), so i'll take that out.  u is from an earlier call, ill put that in to clear things up. thanks!

Comment: Ok, so the next thing would be to get a stack trace with errors. Also, can you please put the whole view function?

Comment: Also, another thing I noticed is that you are returning `HttpResponse`s for both the case with sucess as well as in error. This means that the server will return a response with status code `200 OK`, and your ajax will always execute the "success" handler. If you want to indicate the request was invalid You need to return a ```HttpResponseBadRequest```

Comment: thanks lullis! I think my problem is that i am not grabbing the data from the ajax post. if I attempt to print(new_owner), i get nothing

Answer (score 1):

Well I didn't find an answer per se, but I did find a way to work around what my actual problem. I think the problem i was having was processing the output of serializing the form. The POST data looked like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'asset_owner': ['csrfmiddlewaretoekn=@#$.......&first_name=bob%middlename=""%last_name="smith"']}
```

So I changed my JS/jQuery to the following:

```
var data_to_go = {}
data_to_go['first_name'] = $('input#id_first_name').val();
data_to_go['middle_name'] = $('input#id_middle_name').val()
data_to_go['last_name'] = $('input#id_last_name').val()
$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: '/input/assets/joint_owner/',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
    data: {"asset_owner" : JSON.stringify(data_to_go) },
```

The POST data now looks like:

```
<QueryDict{'asset_owner' : {"first_name" : "bob", "middle_name": "", "last_name" : "smith"}}
```

I can then simply saving the data in the view via

```
    a = json.loads(request.POST.get('asset_owner'))
    new_joint_owner = forms_a.AssetJointOwnerForm(a)
```

Not sure why I was getting the crsf-token like that in the serialize form, but its something that I should probably figure out down the road.

Comment: The problem is, it looks like you are sending a json string as the payload for the whole form. This is certainly going to make things confusing toyour form handler. You have two choices: either make the browser side send normal form data, or convert it to json, and deserialize it into a Python object before sending to your django form class.

Comment: Lull can you add that as an answer so I can accept it. I think that's exactly my problem

Comment: Done. I'd suggest you do this jquery posting json and deserializing on the server on your own, as an exercise. Once you figure out what is going on and if you really decide on having a json API of some sort for your web application, you should take a look at [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), it does this for you and many other things.